# i.landsat.toar doesn't Work With Band 6 of Landsat 7 in Grass 7

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing, landsat

I'm facing an issue when running i.landsat.toar with a Landsat 7 image, here's the list of files:

- LE70010752014040CUB00_B1
- LE70010752014040CUB00_B2
- LE70010752014040CUB00_B3
- LE70010752014040CUB00_B4
- LE70010752014040CUB00_B5
- LE70010752014040CUB00_B6_VCID_1
- LE70010752014040CUB00_B6_VCID_2
- LE70010752014040CUB00_B7
- LE70010752014040CUB00_B8

When the command is processing the bands, it gets stuck in band 6 and gives this error message:

```
ERROR: Unable to open header file for raster map <LE70010752014040CUB00_B61@>.
```

The rest of the band (7 and 8) aren't processed, neither with reflectance or radiance selected.

I configured the `input_prefix=LE70010752014040CUB00_B` and `output_prefix=reflectance_`

Comment: band6 is for temperature, did you configured the output?

Comment: yes, with output_prefix=reflectance_

Comment: When you work with temperature you don´t use reflectance. use output_prefix=_toar (I read the grass documentation and it doesn´t include a parameter to TOA temperature). Also you can try changing the name of the band from "LE70010752014040CUB00_B6_VCID_1" to "LE70010752014040CUB00_B61". Landsat 7 have to ways to name the band 6 (with and without _VCID_), but change the metadata of the file too.

Comment: I don't need the reflectance of the band 6, my problem is that grass stops working with the rest of the bands, and i need the reflectance of bands 7 and 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no so elegant, but renaming LE70010752014040CUB00_B6_VCID_1 to LE70010752014040CUB00_B61 do the trick. If there's a way i can do this with patterns it'll be better.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove temperature bands (LE70010752014040CUB00_B6_VCID_1 &
LE70010752014040CUB00_B6_VCID_2) from folder. Then grass will process 7 and 8 bands too.